# How to convert MP4 (h264/aac) file to F4F fragments for HDS (Adobe)

Tags: c, video-streaming, libav

I am looking for some input on how to programmatically convert mp4 files to fragmented f4f files with accompanying manifests.

I currently have an implementation for creating segmented MPEG2-TS files with accompanying manifest for Apples HLS, and want to create a similar piece of software for Adobes HDS.

My code is based on Libav (alternatively, ffmpeg), so I was hoping they had native support for muxing f4f files, but I have not been able to find any resources for it.

What I am specifically looking for:

- How (if) the format is used in `libav`?
- If there is any special requirements (such as the `h264_mp4toannexb` filter required for converting MP4 to MPEG2 TS)?
- Any sample code (even if it's not using `libav`/`ffmpeg`)
- An easy-to-read manifest specification.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you have to read mp4/f4f specification, and implementation it your self.

1. MP4 file format: ISO/IEC 14496-14
2. f4f file format: It is included in the f4v specification.(http://www.adobe.com/cn/devnet/f4v.html)

The code of mod_h264_streaming (http://h264.code-shop.com/trac) may be helpful.